# MongoDB aggregate Implement PHP driver

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have database

```
db.teacher.insert
([ {name:'budi', address: 'cibubur', tarif: 10000}, 
{name: 'sinta', address: 'depok', tarif: 100000}, ])
```

**if done in cmd results like this use aggregate**

```
db.teacher.aggregate([{ $match: {name: "budi" } },
 { $group: { _id:"$name", count: {$sum: 1 }}} ])
```

this is result `{ "_id" : "budi", "count" : 3 }`

if I want to implement native php like what I tried it like this the results don't match

```
$commands = [ 'count' => 'name' ];
$command = new \MongoDB\Driver\Command($commands); 
$cursor = $manager->executeCommand('teacher', $command); 
foreach ($cursor as $document) {
 var_dump($document); 
}
```

---

Comment: Why would you use it like this, when there is already an `aggregate` method implemented? https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php

Comment: Yes,how to implement in PHP, use driver PHP